# Can counsel functions use ido-flex style matching?

Tags: ido, counsel

I've gotten so used to `(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)` that I really notice its absence in various `counsel-FOO` functions.

Is there a way to turn on flex matching for counsel?  I haven’t been able to find a suitable user option in the code or the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a regular counsel (that is actually using ivy backend) try to setup smth like:

```
  (setq ivy-re-builders-alist '((swiper . ivy--regex-plus)
                                (t . ivy--regex-fuzzy)))
```

It will use fuzzy searching for all ivy/counsel except for swiper.

Also for `M-x` install `smex` package. Then `counsel-M-x` function will use it to provide better results.

[image]